# No searching on primary key with Laravel Scout?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel Scout with TNTSearch Engine at it's working fine but with one little problem. I have the following records.

```
| ID      | Name     |
+---------+----------+
| 9030100 | Car      |
| 9030150 | Car2     |
| 9030200 | Radio    |
```

Here is my query:

```
CatalogProducts::search( $query )->paginate( 15 );
```

When I'm looking for '**car**,' it's returning all records with 'car' in the name.

When I'm looking for '**9030100**', it's returning the product 'Car.'

But when I'm looking for '**9030**', I don't have any results. Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: I think id is integer, if you change id to string, you can search with '9030' and get 9030100'

Comment: @VaheGalstyan No, it's string already

Answer (score 0):

try changing the fuzziness.
set fuzziness to true.

```
'tntsearch' => [
'storage'  => storage_path(), //place where the index files will be stored
'fuzziness' => true,
'fuzzy' => [
    'prefix_length' => 2,
    'max_expansions' => 50,
    'distance' => 2
],
'asYouType' => false,
```

Comment: I feed the data same as you in my db and found this solution. Just change the **distance = 4** and **prefix_length = 4** for 9030 to give result

Comment: Fact is you have to optimize the prefix_length and distance according to your need . Best of luck